# Prediction of text being typed and posting predicted items on a dropdown

Tags: php, javascript

While using the login page of any website if we type "a" all recent logins with name starting from "a" appears in a dropdown. How can I implement this on my PHP web page using JavaScript?

Comment: why you want to show all recent login person details??

Comment: anyways you must b talking about [`autosuggest`](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Comment: i do not need recent login details.i just cited an example..all i want is to facilitate my user by predicting already tagged words.

Comment: where you will enter "a" to find all users.

Comment: "a" is just an example..all i want is to facilitate the user to enter info by such that already tagged words can be matched and shown in a dropdownn..i hope i have made this clear..!!

Answer (score 0):

this you can achieve by Asynchronous Javascript(AJAX).

step1: onkeyUp of your textbox call a method

step2: call to your php file using ajax by sending textboxVal

step3: run a join query in your php file for your login details table and user table and use 'LIKE' clause in your query

```
e.g) SELECT a.name FROM usertable a JOIN loginTable b ON a.userId = b.userId WHERE a.name LIKE 'textboxVal%' AND timestamp >= 'lower limit of your recent time'
```

step4 : on receiving response check your response and build dropdown with that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into jQuery UI Autocomplete. In your case, you may want to make ajax call to get a list of matching words (as mentioned in the above answer). Then display it in drop down
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/